# What is the meaning of “laid out” in the sentence- “I laid out your option”?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I am watching the movie Chain of Commander with Steve Austin and Michael Jay White - in the part of the movie when Michael needs to tell where the money is, the hitman Hammond is telling him to tell him where the money is, Michael is saying “ to release his pal before he tells them where the money is",
then Hammond is saying “I laid out your option”

upon checking the dictionary

- lay out - make something easy to understand
- lay out - explain
- lay out - arrange something
- lay out - spend money

so nothing of these meanings means exclude

Any thoughts on that? Can you explain the meaning in this scenario.

Comment: but why this meaning is not listed in the dictionary ?

Comment: Okay sorry. I think I got you confused. Hammond laid out his options for Michael to choose from. Simply meaning Michael has among these particular choices to choose from, none other whatsoever. And given the situation of drama, no situation to bargain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I laid out your options" means (using the dictionary) explained or made easy to understand.  Alternatively you could understand this as meaning "presented".

The metaphor is that there are several option" (imagine the options are written on cards) and the person lays the option-cards out, in front of them, to make the options easy to understand.

It seems that Hammond is "laying out" two options either "you tell me where the money is", or "I hurt/kill your pal."